# App operation without app delegate methods

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

Can you help me to understand why app still work if I delete default app delegate methods such as `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

Comment: Look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate. Your mentioned methods are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part, the declaration of the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol looks like this:

```
public protocol UIApplicationDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    optional public func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication)

    optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool

    optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool

    optional public func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)

    optional public func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)

   ...
```

Note that the functions are declared as *optional*.  This means that code that conforms to the protocol does not have to implement those functions.

If your app doesn't need to do anything special when it enters the background, then you don't need to implement `applicationDidEnterBackground`.  If your app did need to do something, then you would implement that function.

Comment: It's also worth noting that optional protocol methods are only supported on `@objc` protocols, not "pure Swift" ones.

Answer (score 0):

**What is delegate?**

[from documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate)

> A set of methods that are called by the singleton UIApplication object
>   in response to important events in the lifetime of your app.

**Why your app works?**

`applicationWillResignActive` & `applicationDidEnterBackground` are optional delegate methods.

Their sole purpose is to notify your app if those event occurs. If you remove those methods your app will not get notification when your app goes into background or suspended. Since these methods only job is to provide notification it has nothing to do with your running successfully.

Your app only need this methods if it needs to handle background tasks when app is not active.